# Changing list item background color

Tags: android

I have two ListViews split across the screen. I want to achieve the following:
Clicking on a top list item changes it's background color, and the background color for the item in the bottom list at the same position.

I have the following problem: 
The background of the bottom list item changes only after I scroll it off the screen and scroll it back on to the screen. How do I change the color instantly?

Also how do I change the background color of a single item? Right now when I click on an item it changes it's color, when I click on another list item the previous item stays colored. I want to have 1 list item colored at a time. How do I do this?

Here's my code...

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listViewTop, listViewBottom;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listViewTop = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        listViewBottom = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, addUsersToList());

        listViewTop.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        listViewBottom.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }

    private ArrayList<Model> addUsersToList() {
        ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

        modelList.add(new Model("John"));
        modelList.add(new Model("Mary"));
        modelList.add(new Model("Bob"));
        modelList.add(new Model("Tom"));
        modelList.add(new Model("Danny"));
        modelList.add(new Model("Mike"));
        modelList.add(new Model("Ron"));
        modelList.add(new Model("Harry"));
        modelList.add(new Model("Dan"));

        return modelList;
    }

}
```

CustomAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView userTextView;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> usersArray) {
        super(context, 0, usersArray);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Model currentUser = getItem(position);
        View userRowView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (userRowView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            userRowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.user_layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder.userTextView = (TextView) userRowView.findViewById(R.id.userTextView);

            final View finalUserRowView = userRowView;
            viewHolder.userTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    currentUser.setClicked(true);
                    finalUserRowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            });
            userRowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) userRowView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.userTextView.setText(currentUser.getUserName());

        if (currentUser.isClicked())
            userRowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else
            userRowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        return userRowView;
    }
}
```

Model.java:

```
public class Model {

    private String userName;
    private boolean isClicked;

    public Model(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public boolean isClicked() {
        return isClicked;
    }

    public void setClicked(boolean clicked) {
        isClicked = clicked;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Solved my problems, thanks for the help. Here's my adapter:

```
private static Model mSelectedUser = null;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView userTextView;
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> usersArray) {
    super(context, 0, usersArray);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Model currentUser = getItem(position);
    View userRowView = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (userRowView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        userRowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.user_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder.userTextView = (TextView) userRowView.findViewById(R.id.userTextView);
        userRowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) userRowView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.userTextView.setText(currentUser.getUserName());

    userRowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSelectedUser != null)
                mSelectedUser.setClicked(false);

            mSelectedUser = currentUser;
            mSelectedUser.setClicked(true);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    if (currentUser.isClicked()) {
        userRowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        ((ListView) parent).setSelection(position);
        parent.requestFocus();
    }
    else
        userRowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    return userRowView;
}
```

Comment: no solutions works for u??

Comment: not really what I was looking for, I edited my original post with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the layout and android: background = "" to add youre custom color here
like this:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Last question, you have to change the color of previous  colored item to your default color or you can change all items color to default and then change the selected item color.
for the other problem you can use this :
    `myListView.invalidateViews();`

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be help you 
You can use a selector. Change the colors values and modify the below according to your needs.

backgroundlistview.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
  <item  android:state_focused="false" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
  </selector>
```

pressed.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <solid android:color="#FF1A47"/>  // color   
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#0FECFF"/> // border
    <padding android:left="5dp"
     android:top="5dp"
     android:right="5dp"
     android:bottom="5dp"/> 
   <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" // for rounded corners
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
  </shape>
```

normal.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#0FECFF" />

   <padding android:left="5dp"
     android:top="5dp"
     android:right="5dp"
     android:bottom="5dp"/> 
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
   </shape>
```

Set the background drawable to listview custom layout to be inflated for each row

I recommend using a custom listview with a custom adapter.

```
android:background="@drawable/backgroundlistview"
```

If you have not used a custom adapter you can set the listselector to listview as below

```
  android:listSelector="@drawable/backgroundlistview"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: in your activity

```
 listViewTop.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
 listViewBottom.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
 listViewTop.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_light); // replace with your color
 listViewBottom.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Specify singleChoice to choiceMode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.prgmaker.background_color_list.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#0000ff" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="List2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#0000ff" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
</LinearLayout>
```

2. Create Checkable Layout, which allow checked state to be modified automatically when user click a item in ListView, implementing android.widge.Cheackable interface.

```java
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

    private boolean mChecked = false;

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        if (b != mChecked) {
            mChecked = b;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }
}
```

---

3. Define StateListDrawable for item of ListView

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

---

4. Define item layout which background color will be changed as checked state

```xml
<com.prgmaker.background_color_list.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</com.prgmaker.background_color_list.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

5. Remove click related codes except view related code.

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> usersArray) {
        super(context, 0, usersArray);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Model currentUser = getItem(position);
        View userRowView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (userRowView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            userRowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.user_layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder.userTextView = (TextView) userRowView.findViewById(R.id.userTextView);
            userRowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) userRowView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.userTextView.setText(currentUser.getUserName());
        return userRowView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView userTextView;
    }
}
```

6. Last, synchronize checked state between listViewTop(list1) and listViewBottm(list2)

```java
listViewTop.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                listViewBottom.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your adapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView userTextView;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> usersArray) {
        super(context, 0, usersArray);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Model currentUser = getItem(position);
        View userRowView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (userRowView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            userRowView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.user_layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder.userTextView = (TextView) userRowView.findViewById(R.id.userTextView);

            final View finalUserRowView = userRowView;
            viewHolder.userTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
Object posTag = v.getTag("pos");
if(pasTag != null) {
int pos = (int)posTag;
Model model = getItem(pos);
model.setClicked(true);
}
            }});
            userRowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) userRowView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.userTextView.setText(currentUser.getUserName());
viewHolder.userTextView.setTag("pos",position);

        if (currentUser.isClicked())
            userRowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else
            userRowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        return userRowView;
    }
}
```